# How do I merge these individual components into one solid object?

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I used the blender osm to import a map and I find that the terrain becomes a grid of smaller rectangles when in edit mode. See picture below:
[image]

I'm very new to blender so I'm not familiar with controls, but how would I go about merging all of this so it ends up being one solid object?

Answer (score 0):

These small rectangles are called `faces`. It's the surface of your solid object. There is nothing wrong with them and there is no need to merge them. That's normal. The objects are shown in the Outliner in top right of the screeen.

If you're new to Blender I recommend to watch video like this [3D for NOOBS - Livestream Lesson 01](https://youtu.be/mbYf7rHd4I0). It explains 3D stuff and Blender's interface and basics. It's for absolute beginners.

Comment: Thank you. The only reason I want to merge them is because when I try to use the knife object to cut a specific shape out of the polygon, the multiple faces affects the cut.